# Weird behaviour when running shell script with `source` and without

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am expecting the same result when running the below script with source and without.  Is weird that it is giving me a different result when I ran with source and without source.

### Shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

flag="$1"

for i in ${flag//=/ }; do
    echo "item: $i"
done
```

### Execution with source

```
$ . ./test.sh -p=test
item: -p test

$ source ./test.sh -p=test
item: -p test
```

### Execution without source

```
./test.sh -p=test
item: -p
item: test
```

Can someone tell me what different when I ran with source and without ?  I tried `/bin/bash`, `/bin/sh`...., still the same problem.

Comment: Without source is the expected behavior with `bash`. With source indicates there is no word-splitting applied to the unquoted parameter expansion in the `for` loop. Are you sure you aren't using `zsh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `source` runs in the same shell you are currently running in and `./` opens it up into a subshell.

What is happening is you are setting `IFS` in your current shell probably in your `.bashrc` to a value that does not include a space (something like `$'\n'`), which does not get inherited when running `./` but does when using `source`

To fix just reset `IFS` back to its default value:

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
source test.sh -p=test
item: -p
item: test
```